# Why does the following code not change the property in my object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I setup test2.js as follows

```
module.exports.doPrint = doPrint;

var dummy = "initial";

function doPrint(callback) {
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(dummy);
        callback();
    }, 1000);   
}
```

I then have test1.js

```
var test2 = require("./test2");
test2.doPrint(function() {
    console.log("changing");
    test2.dummy = "new value";
});
```

When I run test1.js I get the following

```
initial
changing
initial
changing
```

In other words the value of dummy in test2.js never gets changed to the new value.  Can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not change the value because `dummy` is a local variable (can't be accessed from outside - variables local to the [module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) will be private). To make it work you can change `test2.js` to this:

```
module.exports.doPrint = doPrint;

function doPrint(callback) {
    var that=this;
    this.dummy = "initial";
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(that.dummy);
        callback();
    }, 1000);   
}
```

---

or use:

```
module.exports.doPrint = doPrint;
module.exports.get = get;
module.exports.set = set;

var dummy = "initial";

function get(){
    return dummy
}

function set(new_value){
    dummy=new_value;
}


function doPrint(callback) {
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(dummy);
        callback();
    }, 1000);   
}
```

and `test2.set("new value");` to change the value, if you want it to be a local variable.